# Remote Desktop Connection - Usage of Internet in Remote Machine

Tags: remote-desktop, internet

I have this trivial doubt about a point in Remote Desktop Connection for a long time. Let us say, we have made a remote desktop connection to a machine named 'Remote' from a machine named 'Local'.

Now my question is very simple. If at all, we are surfing anything using the browser of the remote machine, which bandwidth would be made use of? (The remote machine's or the local machine's or the combination of both?)

As far as I know, only the input to the remote machine could be controlled. Hence, my presumption is that the bandwidth of the remote machine would only be consumed.Is my presumption right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're mostly right, but keep in mind - if you're using Remote Desktop Protocol for browsing or viewing a video, connection traffic from 'Local' to 'Remote' will be much more than usual (e.g. using Notepad for text edit). Of course, traffic for viewing pictures will be in low color and compressed, but it will exceed traffic for trivial RDP connection.
Thus, most part of overall traffic will be generated on remote machine, and minor part - during connection with local machine.